# how to use python 3.8 in hydrogen kernel in atom editor

Tags: atom-editor, hydrogen

I have two different python versions on my macOS, 3.7 (from Anaconda) and 3.8 (installed by Homebrew). I have noticed that Hydrogen kernel uses version 3.7 but couldn't find a way to make it use version 3.8.

When I run it with Hydrogen;

```py
print(sys.version)
>> 3.7.7 (default, Mar 26 2020, 10:32:53) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]
```

and from terminal with python3 command

```py
>> 3.8.2 (default, Mar 11 2020, 00:29:50) 
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)]
```

Can someone guide me please? Thanks!

Comment: what is wrong with version 3.7?

Comment: you have a real dilemma because 3.7 is in a conda environment while 3.8 is not.  You need to set up a virtual environment for version 3.8 and then try running it.  I'm not sure how to do that because I use the Anaconda distribution,

Comment: python 3.7 has discrepancies over some packages that I use in my project so, while I'm working on my project right now, I want to switch to python 3.8. And instead of running the whole script at one time, I want to use Hydrogen to go over the block by block.. @jmh

Comment: If you are having problems try running in a virtual environment and be sure to activate it before running.

Comment: is virtual environment really necessary? Can't I just switch with a Hydrogen command in the editor? @jmh